# How to convert MBR with extended partition to GPT?

Tags: partitioning, mbr, gpt

I have a disk with *extended partition*, and are all used. Now, I want to convert this disk to GPT. But GPT does not support extended partition. I wonder if it would be possible? Or maybe the extended partitions will automatically been converted into a primary one under GPT? I have to tried. I don't want to lose my data.

It would be easy if I have an other disk with enough free space so I can just do a backup, convert, then restore. Unfortunately I don't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Gizmo, but you did not answer my question directly :) I wanted to know if after converting MBR partition to GPT, the logical volumes in the extended partition can still be used as the used to be.

I did some experiment, and `gdisk` is able to convert the logical volumes into primary partitions, and retain the old logical volume number, which mean any application that refer to the old logical volume can still use the same partition number to access the new primary partition.

Comment: So you've done it right?

Comment: It seems you are using Linux. May [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from) help

Comment: @Noverull, yep, done and running :)

Answer (score 0):

3rd party utilities support converting to GPT without losing data, I myself use EaseUS Partition Master for this.

remember: when you change your system disk type from/to GPT, you **may** need to update the bootcode/boot partition too! (eg, you need to add an EFI system partition which is for GPT+UEFI boot)

The best way however would be to backup your data and try a 3rd party paritioning utility (perhaps a linux live cd?) and do it,

OR, just backup the data, wipe and convert the drive, and then restore your data